# Implementing Logistic Regression on IBMQ Hardware

Tags: machine-learning, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning

I'm trying to implement a logistic regression inference circuit on NISQ hardware by following some of the proposed approaches below,

[1] Hai-Ling Liu et al.Quantum algorithm for logistic regression. 2019. arXiv:1906.03834 [quant-ph].

[2] Shilu Yan, Hongsheng Qi, and Wei Cui. “Nonlinear quantum neuron: A fundamental building block forquantum neural networks”. In:Physical Review A102.5 (Nov. 2020).issn: 2469-9934.doi:10.1103/physreva.102.052421.url:http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.102.052421.24

I currently have a quantum circuit that realizes a simpler activation function (ReLU) but due its high gate depth, IBMQ results are terrible. I've also considered a circuit that computes the inner product between two amplitude embedded $n$-dimensional vectors producing in effect a quadratic activation function (due to the probability measurement). However, even with a $16$ dimensional input, the error on the inner product is of the order ~35%.

Does anyone have any successful experience in efficiently implementing activation functions using IBMQ?

Thank you!